# How to contact Schengen Immigration Officers?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, italy, schengen-visas

I have a valid Schengen multiple-entry visa issued by the French consulate. However, in my travel period of 9 days I am spending 2 days in France and the rest in Italy (My initial itinerary was 5 days in France and 4 in Italy).

1. Can I accommodate this change with the same visa?
2. When I called the French consulate, they told me to contact "Immigration Office". They were not giving any information on how to contact them and which immigration office.

So, which Immigration Office should I talk to / get clearance from? (Google is not helping me much here)

Comment: France and Italy are both members of schengen, so I'm guessing it doesn't matter where you'll be spending most of your time.

Comment: @lord2701 Schengen does require you to apply for your visa from the main country of your visit. This is to prevent 'visa shopping', which is where you want to go to country A but you apply for a visa from country B because B is more likely to approve the application.

Comment: Like why have such rules which is confusing?

Answer (score 5):

If this is going to be your first visit on this visa, you should cancel your visa and apply for a new one. There is no way to change your visa from one given out by France to one given out by Italy.
For second and later visits, it does not matter which Schengen countries you visit and how long you stay in each, as long as you remain at most the number of days allowed for each visit and at most 90 days in each 180 day period. (Additional restrictions may apply and will be mentioned in the visa if so.)

How easy it will be for you to travel with the 'wrong' visa does depend on your nationality and how difficult it is for people from your country/in your circumstances to get a visa.
It is in the entry interview on coming into the Schengen zone that you will be asked about your plans. If you can keep it vague, some days in France, some days in Italy, they might accept it.

If you had to supply details for all hotels and all internal travel, you better not change the visa by so much. In the entry interview they will want to see details and will not accept such a change, might send you home without allowing you to enter.

On the other hand, if you are one of the lucky people who get a visa with very little information needed from you, you can take more risks. Officially you are not allowed to do the change you plan, but you will likely not be asked about it. In that case the interview will likely not go into details but it still can. Never lie to immigration officers but being vague or not having detailed plans yet might work.

Best is to change your plans back to stay in France the longest, so your plans match your visa again for the first use of your multiple visit visa, for later visits you can visit any of the Schengen countries unless your visa specifies countries you are or are not allowed to enter. (Which is very rare.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to contact the *Polizia di Frontiera* at the Italian airport where you'll enter. Explain your situation in perfect detail, ask them to check their policy with their chief officer, and get his/her name.

Rome-Fiumicino Airport: +39 665 953 595

Milan-Malpensa Airport: +39 258 584 511

Bergamo Airport: +39 354 203 511

Venice Airport: +39 412 692 411